# 500 error after starting docker container instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, docker, iis, azure-container-instances

I'm getting a 500 error after starting a Docker container.  I can see that the website is running from the command prompt into the running Docker using CMD.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot>\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site

SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:Started)
```

I added to my Web.config, but it didn't help

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

If I stop the website, the 500 error goes away and the connection just hangs endlessly.  So I think that proves telemetry or some Azure process is not getting in the way.

This works from my local Docker Desktop.

I can't see anywhere in the Azure interface where I might find event errors.

I can't load static resources either.  So like http://myip/someimage.png does not load in my browser.  Just a 500 error.

Anyone know how I can figure out what the error is?

Comment: If this is your first time with IIS and Windows container, please try to enable IIS Manager there, https://halfblood.pro/remote-management-of-containerized-iis-instances-on-windows-server-core-f6864c74917f so that you can utilize IIS log settings to enable IIS log files and FRT. They should tell you more about those 500 errors, and the culprit should be clear then.

Comment: The same question you have already asked here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1393516/500-error-after-starting-docker-container-instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1393516/500-error-after-starting-docker-container-instance).